# json text or perl structure exceeds maximum nesting level (max_depth set too low?)

Tags: xml, json, perl

I am getting the following error from JSON's `encode_json`:

> json text or perl structure exceeds maximum nesting level (max_depth set too low?)

The code is in question is

```
my $jsonString = encode_json($dataXML);
```

`$dataXML` was produced by XML::Simple's `XMLin`. Any pointers about how to remove this error?

Comment: created to show the location of error. This a dummy sample of a complicated business code.

Comment: Don't do that. Wrong code is worse than partial code.

Comment: ohh ok, but you have understood the error here right?

Comment: Only because the title was enough to understand what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You get that error from JSON::PP when the structure has 512 levels of nesting. It's probably meant to catch unserializable reference loops (`my $data = { }; $data->{foo} = $data;`) and to prevent malicious attempts to use up all your memory.

If those aren't your problems, if the issue is simply that you need to support ginormous structures, you can increase the threshold using `->max_depth`. Keep mind that

```
encode_json($data)
```

is short for

```
my $json = JSON->new->utf8;
$json->encode($data)
```

so you can use

```
my $json = JSON->new->utf8->max_depth(...);
$json->encode($data)
```

Alternatively, JSON::XS might not have that check. If it doesn't, simply installing JSON::XS will avoid the error. That's on top of speeding up your encoding and decoding.

Comment: i have added a maximum depth of 2048 for line my $json = JSON->new->utf8->max_depth(2048);

Comment: nope same error even after setting maximum depth to 5000, more then that is causing a crash. The only difference between a failing case and non-failing case is just one extra tag, not sure what it is creating so much difference

Comment: Then maybe the error is legit? No matter how much you raise `max_depth`, you won't be able to store a cyclic structure using JSON.

Comment: The doc says: `$json->max_depth([$maximum_nesting_depth])` Have you try: `->max_depth([ 2048 ])`?

Comment: @Eugen Konkov, The square brackets indicate that the argument is optional (in which case the current value is returned), not that you should pass in an array ref.

Comment: @Eugen Konkov, That's something to take up with the maintainers, not me.

Comment: @ikegami: But I use `$json->max_depth([600])` and its works fine ) as in the Doc example

Comment: @Eugen Konkov, No, it doesn't work fine. It sets the depth the numerical value of the reference (e.g. `55321800`) instead of `600`. /// I said something wrong earlier, though. Omitting the argument doesn't cause `->max_depth` to return the existing value; it effectively allows unlimited depth.